# Change in the average geodesic distance of a graph when flipping a single edge

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Is there any way to find how much would the average geodesic distance of a graph will change if I add or remove a single edge that's faster then calculating the distance before and after and then subtracting?

I'm doing a Metropolis Monte Carlo simulation of a system whose state is represented by an undirected graph. The energy of the system depends on the average geodesic distance of this graph.

At each monte carlo step I must propose a modification of the graph and then calculate the change in energy due to that modification. I'm just selecting a random edge and flipping it (add the edge if it's not present, remove the edge if it's present). What I do now is kind of brute force:

```
Graph = initialize;
L = avgGeodesicLength(Graph)
E0 = energy(L)
for(i = 0; i < mcsteps; i++) {
   newGraph = copy Graph;
   flip a random edge of newGraph;
   L = avgGeodesicLength(newGraph);
   E1 = energy(L);
   dE = E1 - E0
   if (metropolis criteria(dE) is true) {
      Graph = newGraph;
      E0 = E1;
   } 
   else {
      throw the copy away and keep the current state;
   }
}
```

I'd rather do this:

```
Graph = initialize;
L = avgGeodesicLength(Graph);
E0 = energy(L);
for(i = 0; i < mcsteps; i++) {
   edge = random edge of Graph;
   dL = difference in AvgGeodesicLength if I flip edge;
   dE = differenceInEnergy(dL);
   if (metropolis criteria(dE) is true) {
      flip edge; 
      E0 += dE;
   }
   else { do nothing;}
}
```

if calculating the difference in energy was substantially faster than calculating the energy itself. This is possible if there's a way to calculate the difference in the average geodesic length if a given edge is flipped in a much faster way (big-O-wise).

Is there a way to do this? I know it's difficult to predict what paths will be affected by a change in a single edge, but... maybe I'm lucky! :D

EDIT: I don't care whatever representation I must use for any algorithms you have in mind. If it saves my time, I'm willing to do it.

My graphs are usually kind of small (number of vertices usually less than a hundred, number of edges varies between a handful and fully connected). The problem is that I must repeat this loop for many, many steps to achieve equilibrium and them calculate many observables for each of many, many different conditions... :(

EDIT 2: I don't need the individual geodesic paths or their lengths, only the average geodesic lengths.